# Understanding the Difference Between Data Mapper and Active Record in TypeORM

Tags: database, typeorm

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working with TypeORM and trying to grasp the distinction between Data Mapper and Active Record patterns. I've read the documentation, but I'm still struggling to understand how they apply in practical scenarios. Could someone please help clarify this for me?

Here's what I'm specifically trying to understand:

1. What is the fundamental difference between Data Mapper and Active Record patterns in TypeORM?
2. How does the implementation of each pattern differ in TypeORM?
3. Are there specific use cases where one pattern is more suitable than the other?

Any guidance, examples, or explanations would be greatly appreciated. I'm eager to enhance my understanding of these concepts.

Thank you!